# What is the best way to use Google maps API in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to use Google Maps API in two way:

1. To store coordinates of a marker in database
2. To display objects stored in database on map

I was suggested to use [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) for both. Googling I found [this library](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library) that can be used as well for both purposes. I am familiar with html, css and PHP but I have minor experience with JS so I would love to avoid it. The library, if I got it correctly, generates JS code. So it would be a lot more easier to use library.

My question is about quality of both options. Which option would produce higher efficiency? The map is supposed to display a lot of markers from database.

I am sorry if this is silly question but I want to know for sure that I have chosen right tool before getting my hands dirty.

Comment: The library you have found is really nice, bookmarked.  From what I can see you can store the long/lat and other options into a table and call them as needed.  Give it a go.

Comment: Thats the thing - library looks good, easy to use. My concerns are about the quality of solution. Will the easier way be better one as well? I will try with library but would love if someone who had worked both ways could share his opinion comparing them. Otherwise I will have to try both options just to be sure.

Comment: 2 option will be faster , because i used it well